# Windows batch file command creates file but does not write to it

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a messenger with batch files and I am trying to store a default color setting. I have stored other settings before and have had no problem but this time it creates the file but leaves it blank.

Here is an example:

```
echo Enter the colour you want...
set /p defaultcolor=
if "%defaultcolor%" == "default" @echo 7> "\\user-computer\users\user\documents\codes+stuff\messenger\userdata\%username%\default colour.dll"
if "%defaultcolor%" == "blue" @echo 1> "\\user-computer\users\user\documents\codes+stuff\messenger\userdata\%username%\default colour.dll"
if "%defaultcolor%" == "green" @echo 2> "\\user-computer\users\user\documents\codes+stuff\messenger\userdata\%username%\default colour.dll"
if "%defaultcolor%" == "aqua" @echo 3> "\\user-computer\users\user\documents\codes+stuff\messenger\userdata\%username%\default colour.dll"
```

If anybody can spot the problem I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I should also note that the if statement works fine.

Comment: Sorry! I'm using Windows command line.

Comment: I think what you meant was an INI file which usually contains the settings for a program. A DLL is essentially an executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a space between your number and the redirect symbol.

```
@ECHO 2> file
```

is interpreted as

Redirect the STDERR output of ECHO to *file*

```
@ECHO 2 > file
```

is interpreted as

Write *2* to *file*

Note you can also use the caret escape as follows

```
echo Enter the colour you want...
set /p defaultcolor=
if "%defaultcolor%" == "default" @echo ^7> "\\user-computer\users\user\documents\codes+stuff\messenger\userdata\%username%\default colour.dll"
if "%defaultcolor%" == "blue" @echo ^1> "\\user-computer\users\user\documents\codes+stuff\messenger\userdata\%username%\default colour.dll"
if "%defaultcolor%" == "green" @echo ^2> "\\user-computer\users\user\documents\codes+stuff\messenger\userdata\%username%\default colour.dll"
if "%defaultcolor%" == "aqua" @echo ^3> "\\user-computer\users\user\documents\codes+stuff\messenger\userdata\%username%\default colour.dll"
```

Comment: To cement your knowledge, you should understand that `echo eggs 7>spam.txt 1>&7` will open "spam.txt" with write access and  duplicate its file descriptor to FD 7. Then `1>&7` duplicates FD 7 to the standard output FD 1, effectively working as if you had used `1>spam.txt` or more simply `>spam.txt`.

Comment: @Stavr00 Does this also apply to appending (>> instead of >) to the file?

Comment: @DarkEncrypter: yes, it's the same.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably shorten it a little:

```
Set/P "defaultcolor=Enter the colour you want... "
(
    If /I "%defaultcolor%"=="default" Echo 7
    If /I "%defaultcolor%"=="blue" Echo 1
    If /I "%defaultcolor%"=="green" Echo 2
    If /I "%defaultcolor%"=="aqua" Echo 3
)>"\\user-computer\users\user\documents\codes+stuff\messenger\userdata\%username%\default colour.dll"
```

*Note that `.dll` files don't usually contain standard text.*

Answer (score 2):

some other methods:

```
echo 5 >file.txt
```

Note: there is a space after the `5`, which is written to the file too.

```
>file.txt echo 5
```

Note: most robust solution imho.

```
(echo 5)>file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the @ in front of your echos and put a space before the >

Comment: Removing the @ doesn't make any difference.